# AngularJs CLI An unhandled exception occurred:catch clause variable is not an Error instance, while creating angular component using ng g c my-compnnt

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Getting below error while creating component using ng g c my-component

'**An unhandled exception occurred: catch clause variable is not an Error instance**
See "path-to-file\angular-errors.log" for further details.'

And file contains below stack trace:
**[error] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: catch clause variable is not an Error instance
at assertIsError (C:\Users\sam\node_modules@angular\cli\src\utilities\error.js:16:26)
at GenerateCommandModule.runSchematic (C:\Users\sam\node_modules@angular\cli\src\command-builder\schematics-command-module.js:311:43)
at async GenerateCommandModule.handler (C:\Users\sam\node_modules@angular\cli\src\command-builder\command-module.js:109:24)**

**No luck even after updating angular cli**

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

below is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "my-sample-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have the Angular CLI as a dev dependency so you don't need a global installation, just `npm install`  and run.

Comment: AngularJS is the original "Angular" with a current version of 1.8 and does not have a CLI.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is most likely due to the fact that you have two modules in src/app.
So when you try to generate the component, the angular cli does not know where to register this new component.

And that is why the `--skip-import` option was a workaround for the issue.
However the proper way to handle this would be specifying the module in the `ng g c` something like this:

```
ng g c my-component --module=app.module
```

And the problem is not happening anymore and you register your component in the module as it is intended

Comment: This issue is arising from v14. Specifying the module resolves the issue.

Comment: @SajibAcharya -  It didn't fix it, no matter what I try. Any other way to fix it?

Comment: @securecurve are you trying to generate a new component in the app module itself?

Comment: Thanks, @SajibAcharya! I was trying to create a module with a module file, routing file, and flat component files inside that module.  I fixed it by updating the Angular version from 14.0.0 to 14.1.1, then issuing this command: `ng g m modules/myMod --route my-module  --module app.routing`

Comment: or you can make it `--module app.module` if you have the routing object in the `app.module.ts` file.

Answer (score 4):

Yesterday i had the same problems. I still don`t know why this happen. But when I use --skip-import as parameter the command is running without any errors.

example:

```
ng g c modules/bla/component/test --skip-import
```

This will create a new component with the name test in the folder modules/bla/component (relative to the current path) and skip all the imports in the closest module.

Don`t forget to add the component in the declations array in the linked module file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I found that if the file is named with dots it gives error, for example:
src/app/application.material.module.ts
or
src/app/application-material.module.ts

If you change the name to src/app/application-material-module.ts it works.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your command it's working for me.
Please check your path where you fire this command: `ng g c my-component`

[image]

Comment: Issue is when I create custom MaterialModule (material.module.ts)

Comment: ```import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';


@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
 
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }```

Comment: As soon as I add material.module.ts in app folder it starts giving above error while creating new component

Comment: i tried in my angular(version 11) , didnt gave me an error, worked for me.
i create "material.module.ts" file in app folder, then create the component using cmd(ng g c testcomp). working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I want to leave my testimony because I had the same problem. the error occurred to me when I tried to better organize the code, in detail I moved the app.component files to a folder (and I updated the dependencies).

[these are the files that have undergone a change between the last commit in which I don't have the problem and the first commit in which I have it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIMoc.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**ADD THE MODULE FLAG (--module=app) TO THE COMMAND**

```
ng g c test2 --module=app
```