# Angular CLI: An unhandled exception occurred: catch clause variable is not an Error instance, while creating a service

Tags: angular

I attempted to use the following command to make a new service: `ng g s serviceName`

I received the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: catch clause variable is not an Error instance
> See "/private/var/folders/39/2pkykr9132vfjd74lbx8ddh00000gp/T/ng-0qxg77/angular-errors.log" for further details.

When opening the error log file indicated, I see the following:

> [error] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: catch clause variable is not an Error instance
> at assertIsError ([projectpath]/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/utilities/error.js:16:26)
> at GenerateCommandModule.runSchematic ([projectpath]/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/command-builder/schematics-command-module.js:311:43)
> at async GenerateCommandModule.handler ([projectpath]/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/command-builder/command-module.js:109:24)

This is similar to the question posted below, except while generating a service rather than a component. So the `--skip-import` and `--module` flags that people suggested are not applicable.
[AngularJs CLI An unhandled exception occurred:catch clause variable is not an Error instance, while creating angular component using ng g c my-compnnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73110924/angularjs-cli-an-unhandled-exception-occurredcatch-clause-variable-is-not-an-er)

Line 109 of the command-module.js file indicated is the following:

```
exitCode = await this.run(camelCasedOptions);
```

Looking at that and the surrounding lines of code, I honestly have no idea what's going on that would be causing this error. Any suggestions at all would be very welcome.